# How to take control of a running Word application from another Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to grab a running word application and insert some text.

The VBA/Macro code is run from another separate Microsoft application such as Word or Excel. Is this possible?

Comment: You need a handle to the Word/Excel instance in order to be able to insert text. What have you tried so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy. You need just this simple code to put inside any Excel, PP, Outlook Module. To catch Word from Word... you don't need it, you are just in.

```
Sub catch_word()
    Dim WRD As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WRD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If WRD Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Word Application is not open"
    Else
        'add new document and add text into it
        Dim DOC
        Set DOC = WRD.documents.Add
        DOC.Content.Text = "First text into document"
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit** If you know the name of the document which is already opened you could go this simply way to catch it and put some text into it:

```
Sub catch_word_document()
    Dim WRD As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WRD = GetObject("Document1")

    If WRD Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Word Application is not open"
    Else
        'add text into it
        WRD.Content.Text = "First text into document"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KazJaw.
How ever, I want to add text to the opened Word document and not add another.
Based on your code

```
Sub catch_word()
   Dim WRD As Object
   Dim WRD_WINDOWS As Object
   Dim strTemp As String

  On Error Resume Next
Set WRD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If WRD Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Word Application is not open"
Else

    Set WRD_WINDOWS = WRD.Windows

    For Each win In WRD_WINDOWS
        If (win.Document.FullName = "Document1") Then
            win.Document.Range(Start:=125, End:=134).Text = "Some Text"
            strTemp = win.Document.Range(Start:=5, End:=10).Text
        End If

    Next
End If
```

Comment: I didn't know you need to take control of the document which is already opened (I thought of application only, not document). If so check quite simply way to do it in re-edited answer of mine.